Azure DevOps create a query showing bugs in the project for each requirement
I need to create in Azure DevOps a query showing bugs in the project for each requirement.
I just created a Requirement containing a Test case Child.
Test case contains a Bug Child.
For example like this (report tee).
enter image description here
Now I'd like to generate a report  showing bugs in the project for each requirement, but I can create only a report with all bugs in the project without relation with the requirement.
It is possible to do this via Azure Query in order then to generate a graphical Chart?
enter image description here
I need to create in Azure DevOps a query showing bugs in the project group by each requirement.


It is possible to do this via Azure Query in order then to generate a graphical Chart?

I am afraid that there is no built-in feature in Azure DevOps can create the chart based on tree or direct link queries (Parent-Child Query) result.
Currently, Azure DevOps only supports creating the chart based on flat-list query. Refer to this doc: Track progress with status and trend query-based charts
If you create the query to list the Parent and child work items, it will show the error: Charting is not supported for tree or direct link queries  when you navigate to the chart tab.

This means that the query used to filter Parent-Child relationship can not generate chart in Azure DevOps.
I can fully understand your requirement. Here is a suggestion ticket with the same requirement: Create chart for a tree query or a direct links query.

Hi thanks for your reply.

Aniway, I need to create a flat query in order to generate a Pie graphical chart, containing all bug status grup by each requirement.

Moreover and unfortunally, the suggested link in the ticket you mentioned is no more available: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519/suggestions/16692931

@AlessandroCarnevali I can understand your requirement. When you use flat query, it can create  the pie chart, but it can only show flat bug work items and not able to show related work items. And the other two query types can show the related work items, but they are not able to create chart. These are limitations. For a workaround, you can  use tree or direct link queries  to query the bugs and related requirements. Then you need to export to excel or powerbi to generate report.

And the suggestion ticket in the answer is this url: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/create-chart-for-a-tree-query-or-a-direct-links-qu/365598 This is a valid suggestion ticket.
